# Laravel 8 multiple where clause query doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

Sorry for my English,
I have 2 example:

```
$data= users::where('email', $email)->get(); 
$data= users::where('email', $email)->where('name', $name)->get();
```

I use debug to check the values they can get and the first example work but the second cant get anything and just show:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#328 ▼
#items: []
}
```

How can i use multiple to check many condition at the same time,
Thanks guys

Comment: `->where()->where()` means "Where ... AND where ...". Did you mean to use `->where()->orWhere()`?

Comment: I mean AND and result is checked by 2 condition at the same, orWhere just check one of them

Comment: Then your original query should be working. What is `$email` and `$name`? Do you have a record (or records) in your database that has that `email` and `name`? Can you provide the raw query that gets your results? The code should be working, but your values and/or records in your database are not what you think they are.

Comment: I use this query in MySQL and it can gets results:

SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email LIKE 'tranhuynhquocbao232@gmail.com' AND name LIKE 'Quoc Bao'. In project i replace the values by info from the form

Comment: Aside from the fact you're using `LIKE` for no apparent reason, that _should_ be the same query. If you replace `->get()` with `->toSql()`, then do `dd($data);`, you should be able to see the query being generated.

Answer (score 0):

with Eloquent, you can pass all your clauses as an Array. 
Here:

```
$data= users::where([['email', $email],['name', $name]])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue may be that you should be using `orWhere()`.

```
$data = User::where('email', $email)->where('name', $name)->get();
```

This will return User records where the `email` column is equal to `$email` *AND* where the `name` column is equal to `$name`.

```
$data = User::where('email', $email)->orWhere('name', $name)->get();
```

This will return User records where the `email` column is equal to `$email` *OR* where the `name` column is equal to `$name`.